# Does this line of code make sense?

Tags: code

I'm looking at the following code, specifically this line "if (nOffboardingsInProgress++ == 0)", and I'm wondering about the way that line is written. Don't you need to first increment nOffboardingsInProgress and then compare it to 0?

```
function offboard(address term) external whenNotPaused {
        require(canOffboard[term], "LendingTermOffboarding: quorum not met");

        GuildToken(guildToken).removeGauge(term);

        if (nOffboardingsInProgress++ == 0)
//MORE CODE
```

Answer (score 0):

I think code review is frowned upon on stack exchange, esp. without things like what the `if` is doing.

I'm not sure it is strange if you want to increase a variable for the next time a function is called, but check if the last time it was called met some threshold and if so do something this time.

A contracts variables can only be updated when functions are called on them, so would make sense if the last transaction to offboard would be the one to update the value that we need this time around. Letting us no where are no more.